# Why newer versions of C++ don't allow definition of pure method inside class declaration?

Tags: c++, oop, chain

Why MSVC++ 2015 and its earlier versions allowed the definition of a `pure virtual method` inside the class declaration but On `GCC 4.9` and I guess `MSVC++ 2017` don't allow that:

```
    #include <iostream>     

    class A{
        public:
            virtual void Foo() = 0;
    };

    class B: public A {
        public:
            virtual void Foo() = 0 { std::cout << "B::Foo()" << std::endl;
            }; // Allowed on MSVC 2015 and old versions

            //virtual void Foo() = 0; // on newer versions
    };

    //void B::Foo(){
    //  std::cout << "B::Foo()" << std::endl;
    //}     // Ok here!

    class C : public B{
        public:
            void Foo(){
                B::Foo();
                std::cout << "C::Foo()" << std::endl;
            }
    };

    int main(){

    //  A aObj; // error
    //  B bObj; // error
        C cObj; // correct
        cObj.Foo();

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the language grammar strictly allows it. I agree that it should.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: The program runs correctly without a hitch on Msvc++ 2015!

Comment: Probably because MSVC didn't implement the grammar described in the standard - most compilers don't..

Comment: "MSVC++ 2015 and earlier versions of C++" Perhaps that's MSVC++ 2015 and earlier versions of *MSVC*? This syntax was never valid in C++.

Comment: @n.m.: I edited the topic.

Comment: "Why does/did MSVC have a bug" is a vacuous question. Such is life.

Comment: It was a Visual C++ **language extension**. Visual C++ also had or maybe still has an extension where you can qualify overrides in a class with the name of the class the base version comes from. The g++ compiler has other language extensions, such as variable length arrays.

Comment: VC++17 still allows it, even when properties / C/C++/ language / "Disable language extensions" is set to Yes. So that's a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) explicitly mentions that that is not allowed (e.g. C++14, §10.4./2)

> A function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a
>   definition — end note ] [ Example: struct C { virtual void f() = 0 {
>   }; // ill-formed }; — end example ]